# Why does BUTTON.setEnabled(true); lead to a nullpointer exception if BUTTON is not null?

Tags: android

I get

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ente.testen.Testen.onCreate(Testen.java:210)
```

pointing to

```
            btnAendern.setEnabled(true);
```

in

```
    final Button btnAendern = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAendern);

    final Intent absicht = getIntent();
        if (absicht == null)
            btnAendern.setEnabled(false);
        else
            btnAendern.setEnabled(true);
```

Android Studio 1.0 does not show `R.id.btnAendern` underlined, so it does find it. Using

```
    if (btnAendern != null) {
        if (absicht == null)
            btnAendern.setEnabled(false);
        else
            btnAendern.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

Still let's Android point to `btnAendern.setEnabled(true);`.

What could be the cause for this?

Here is the full error log:

```
12-14 00:23:27.949  17965-17965/ente.testen E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ente.testen, PID: 17965
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ente.testen/ente.testen.testen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ente.testen.testen.onCreate(testen.java:210)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the complete Activity class, this little snippet of code doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the IDE finds it doesn't mean the button exists.  If you haven't set a content view or you set a content view that doesn't have that button it still returns null.  One of those is the case.

Comment: Yep.  The current view tree (whatever you loaded in setContentView...  You *did* call setContentView, didn't you??) does not contain a view with the id R.id.btnAendern.   ...and, btw, did you know that you can simply say: btnAendern.setEnabled(absicht != null)